# Is boost asio timer expected to block on `cancel`?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I observe that the `boost::asio::steady_timer` is blocking when the `cancel` is called and the callback provided by `async_wait` is already executing. Is it expected behavior? Is it configurable? Why in the first place it have to block?

callstack:

```
#0  __lll_lock_wait () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:135
#1  0x00007f4d4c703dbd in __GI___pthread_mutex_lock (mutex=0x20000616f558) at ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80
#2  0x000070000086ef75 in boost::asio::detail::posix_mutex::lock (this=0x20000616f558) at /source/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/posix_mutex.hpp:52
#3  0x000070000087036e in boost::asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock::scoped_lock (this=0x40000623e970, m=...) at /source/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/conditionally_enabled_mutex.hpp:55
#4  0x00007000009ebf7f in boost::asio::detail::epoll_reactor::cancel_timer<boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> > > (this=0x20000616f520, queue=..., timer=..., 
    max_cancelled=18446744073709551615) at /source/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/epoll_reactor.hpp:62
#5  0x00007000009e8322 in boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::detail::chrono_time_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> > >::cancel (this=0x200006188f60, impl=..., ec=...)
    at /source/boost/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp:144
#6  0x00007000009e5211 in boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, boost::asio::wait_traits<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock> >::cancel (this=0x20009470cfc8)
    at /source/boost/include/boost/asio/basic_waitable_timer.hpp:329
```

Comment: As with much of asio timers are not thread safe and can't be used from multiple threads at the same time

Comment: They are not thread safe as per documentation. So why something should be blocked? It doesnt make the timer thread safe in any case.

Comment: short answer: no. Guesses about the reason for the implementation details are off-topic, mostly.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Most likely the locking I see here is a side-effect of how the timer being used. More to follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was due the fact that we are working in multi-process environment. All processes share the same memory, all objects created on this shared memory, including mutexes, threads etc. To function properly in such a case the mutexes used in the system are created with `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED` attribute. Obviously, `asio` mutexes are not created with such an attribute so I guess this is the problem with the mutexes getting stuck in unexpected locations. Once the `io_context` and `steady_timer` started to execute in only one process it started to work as expected